# Creating hashtable of hashtables using primary key from SQL query result as hashtable key

Tags: sql, powershell, datatable, hashtable

I have a decently sized resultset from a query, and I would like to convert them into a hashtable of hashtables, with each sub hashtable containing a row from the result set, and use the unique ID from each row as the key for the hashtable containing that row. So far I have tried this:

```bsh
$query = "SELECT * FROM [TaskCentre_Staging].[dbo].[vw_IT_PriceList]"

$command = $connection.CreateCommand()
$command.CommandText = $query

$result = $command.ExecuteReader()

$table = New-Object "System.Data.DataTable"
$table.Load($result)

$hashtable = @{}

foreach($line in $table)
{
    $hashtable.Add($line.U_ProductID, $line)
}

$hashtable
```

But this results in something like the following:

```
1 System.Data.DataRow
2 System.Data.DataRow
3 System.Data.DataRow
4 System.Data.DataRow
5 System.Data.DataRow
...
```

How do I get this to work? I've tried looking for hpw to convert datatables to hashtables, but everything I've seen seems only work for a simple hashtable, not the hashtable within a hashtable result that I need.

Answer (score 2):

If you want the data rows as a hashtable of hashtables you need to convert each data rows to a hashtable. Enumerate the properties of the `System.Data.DataRow` objects, remove all (common) properties that you don't want included, put the remaining properties in a new hashtable, then add that hashtable to `$hashtable`.

```
$hashtable = @{}
foreach ($line in $table) {
  $row = @{}
  $line.PSObject.Properties | Where-Object {
    'RowError','RowState','Table','ItemArray','HasErrors' -notcontains $_.Name
  } | ForEach-Object {
    $row[$_.Name] = $_.Value
  }
  $hashtable.Add($row.U_ProductID, $row)
}
```

Comment: I think $row.U_ProductID - is a custom value, and if it's DataTable, it works like this:$hashtable.Add($line.ItemArray[0], $line.ItemArray[1])

Comment: @SergiyDivnych What are you talking about? `$table` is the DataTable, `$line` are DataRows from that table, `$row` is a hashtable that gets populated with values from `$line` (including `U_ProductID`), which is then added to another hashtable `$hashtable`.

Comment: It works for me, with such line of code in the end '$hashtable.Add($line.ItemArray[0], $line.ItemArray[1])' for my DataTable which I get from database using query, but with this value it's crashing 'U_ProductID', so, if it works with this 'U_ProductID' for you, ok, maybe for someone it will works, as I wrote, and I think this 'U_ProductID' is your custom value. So anyway, thanks for your code, it helped me